# Matrix determinant lemma derivation

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

While reading this [wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_determinant_lemma) on the determinant lemma, I stumbled upon this expression (in a proof section):
\begin{equation}
\begin{pmatrix} \mathbf{I} & 0 \\ \mathbf{v}^\mathrm{T} & 1 \end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix} \mathbf{I}+\mathbf{uv}^\mathrm{T} & \mathbf{u} \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix} \mathbf{I} & 0 \\ -\mathbf{v}^\mathrm{T} & 1 \end{pmatrix} =
\begin{pmatrix} \mathbf{I} & \mathbf{u} \\ 0 & 1 + \mathbf{v}^\mathrm{T}\mathbf{u} \end{pmatrix}.
\end{equation}

Although I see that this equation "works", I'm interested in HOW this thing was invented. For example, why we have $u$ term in a central block matrix of the left side?

**UPD**
A little clarification of the question above.

Let
\begin{equation}L = \begin{pmatrix} \mathbf{I} & 0 \\ \mathbf{v}^\mathrm{T} & 1 \end{pmatrix} \end{equation}

I see that
\begin{equation}
L^{-1}=
\begin{pmatrix} \mathbf{I} & 0 \\ -\mathbf{v}^\mathrm{T} & 1 \end{pmatrix} 
\end{equation}

and hence the first equation looks like 
\begin{equation}
L\begin{pmatrix}\mathbf{I + uv^T} & \mathbf{u} \\ 0 & 1\end{pmatrix}L^{-1} = 
\begin{pmatrix} \mathbf{I} & \mathbf{u} \\ 0 & 1 + \mathbf{v}^\mathrm{T}\mathbf{u} \end{pmatrix}.
\end{equation}

I see that $\det(L) = \det(L^{-1}) = 1 $. Hence determinants of RHS and LHS are equal as well.

What I **do not understand** is how we jumped from simple $\begin{pmatrix}\mathbf{I + uv^T} & \mathbf{0} \\ 0 & 1\end{pmatrix}$ or $\begin{pmatrix}\mathbf{I} & \mathbf{u} \\ \mathbf{-v}^T & 1\end{pmatrix}$ to $\begin{pmatrix}\mathbf{I + uv^T} & \mathbf{u} \\ 0 & 1\end{pmatrix}$ for a central part of LHS.

Thank you.

Comment: A block row and column operation on the matrix on the RHS will develop the product on the LHS. Take $-v^T$(Block Row $1$) and add it to Block Row $2$. This results in $\begin{pmatrix}\bf{I} & \bf{u}\\-\bf{v}^T & 1\end{pmatrix}$, and the matrix representing that row operation is $\begin{pmatrix}\bf{I} & 0\\-\bf{v}^T & 1\end{pmatrix}$. Now take (Block Column $2$)$\bf{v}^T$ and add it to Block Column $1$. This will give $\begin{pmatrix}\bf{I + uv^T} & \bf{u}\\0 & 1\end{pmatrix}$, and the matrix representing the column operation is $\begin{pmatrix}\bf{I} & 0\\\bf{v}^T & 1\end{pmatrix}$.

Comment: Putting it altogether, we obtain your stated expression.

Comment: Are you sure you speak of rows, not columns here?

Comment: Are you referring to the first operation? Yes, I mean $\begin{pmatrix}\bf{I}&\bf{u}\end{pmatrix}$ is premultiplied by $-{\bf v}^T$ and added to $\begin{pmatrix}0&1+{\bf v}^T\bf{u}\end{pmatrix}$.

Comment: I've clarified the question a bit, hope you'll see where I'm lost ...

Comment: Do you understand from my first comment how matrices $L$ and $L^{-1}$ were obtained? If so, then all you need is that matrices of row operations act by multiplication on the right, whereas matrices of column operations act on the left.

Comment: Ok, I seem to understand now. You mean that original matrix is the central part of LHS multiplied by $L^{-1}$ term? Ok, this is what I was missing.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is just Gaussian elimination. We begin with $\pmatrix{I+uv^T&0\\ 0&1}$ and we want to eliminate the summand $uv^T$ in the first sub-block using row or column additions (so that the determinant is preserved):
\begin{align*}
\pmatrix{I+uv^T&0\\ 0&1}\pmatrix{I&0\\ -v^T&1}&=\pmatrix{I+uv^T&0\\ -v^T&1},\\
\pmatrix{I&u\\ 0&1}\pmatrix{I+uv^T&0\\ -v^T&1}&=\pmatrix{I&u\\ -v^T&1},\\
\pmatrix{I&0\\ v^T&1}\pmatrix{I&u\\ -v^T&1}&=\pmatrix{I&u\\ 0&1+v^Tu}.
\end{align*}
Put them together, we get
$$
\pmatrix{I&0\\ v^T&1}\pmatrix{I&u\\ 0&1}\pmatrix{I+uv^T&0\\ 0&1}\pmatrix{I&0\\ -v^T&1}=\pmatrix{I&u\\ 0&1+v^Tu}.
$$
If you want, you may perform a further column addition to make the RHS block-diagonal:
$$
\pmatrix{I&0\\ v^T&1}\pmatrix{I&u\\ 0&1}\pmatrix{I+uv^T&0\\ 0&1}\pmatrix{I&0\\ -v^T&1}\pmatrix{I&-u\\ 0&1}=\pmatrix{I&0\\ 0&1+v^Tu}.
$$
[Sherman–Morrison–Woodbury formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Woodbury_matrix_identity) and [Schur complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schur_complement) are also derived in the same spirit.

Comment: Exactly the kind of explanation I was looking for! Thank you, sir )

Answer (score 6):

I have no idea how this was invented and what was the original motivation, but let me outline a different proof for the formula $\det(I + uv^T) = 1 + v^T u$ which I think is much less magical and more natural.

Set

$$ B = uv^T = \begin{pmatrix} u_1 v_1 & \dots & u_1 v_n \\
u_2 v_1 & \dots & u_2 v_n \\
\vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
u_n v_1 & \dots  & u_n v_n \end{pmatrix} \in M_n(\mathbb{F}). $$

Let us start by finding the characteristic polynomial $p_B(x) = \det(B - xI)$ of $B$. Since $B$ has $\operatorname{rank}(B) \leq 1$, we know that it has at least $n - 1$ eigenvectors associated to the eigenvalue $0$. Since the sum of all eigenvalues must be $\operatorname{tr}(B) = v^T u$, we see that

$$ p_B(x) = \det(B - xI) = (-1)^{n} x^{n-1}(x - v^T u). $$

Now plug in $x = (-1)$ and deduce the required formula:

$$ p_B(1) = \det(B - (-1)I) = \det(B + I) = \det(I + uv^T) = (-1)^n (-1)^{n-1} (-1 - v^T u) = 1 + v^T u.$$

Comment: Dear levap, the point is to understand how this thing was decomposed to block matrices, not to just prove the original statement

Comment: In $p_{B}(x)$ how is the presence of the term $(-1)^{n}$ derived?

Comment: @MattiaMariantoni: The characteristic polynomial $\det(B - xI)$ has as leading coefficient $(-1)^n x^n$.