# Alternative proofs Matrix Determinant Lemma

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, numerical-methods, determinant, matrix-calculus

Well as many of you know wiki has a beautiful proof for the Matrix Determinant Lemma [Wiki's Proof](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_determinant_lemma)

But: How the hell is one supposed to get there on his own? There is no way that when a professor would ask you to proof the lemma in your let's say 4th semester, you will come up with the idea for that proof. So my question is: Are there alternative methods to show the Lemma which are more intuitiv or let's say realistic to come up with?

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2072706/matrix-determinant-lemma-derivation?rq=1 for how that proof could have been found.

Comment: Another proof is given, in extreme detail, in the solution to Exercise 6.59 in my [*Notes on the combinatorial fundamentals of algebra*, version of 10 January 2019](https://github.com/darijgr/detnotes/releases/tag/2019-01-10). The main idea is that $A + u v^T = \left(A \mid u\right) \left(I_n \mid v\right)^T$, where $\left(C \mid D\right)$ means the block matrix $\begin{pmatrix} C & D \end{pmatrix}$. Then use the Cauchy-Binet formula.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start with the lower triangular matrix $I+ue_1^T$ where you know the determinant to be $1+u_1=1+e_1^Tu$.

---

Next, you know that there exist matrices that reflect or rotate any vector $v$ into a multiple of $e_1$, $Qv=\alpha e_1\iff v=αQ^Te_1$ (Householder reflectors, basis completion to an orthonormal basis,...).

Then 
$$
\det(I+uv^T)=\det(I+αue_1^TQ)=\det(I+αQue_1^T)=1+αe_1^TQu=1+v^Tu.
$$

---

After that the general case is simple,
$$
\det(A+uv^T)=\det(A)\det(I+A^{-1}uv^T)=\det(A)(1+v^TA^{-1}u).
$$