# Show that $v^tA^{-1}u\ne -1$ if and only if $A+uv^t$ is invertible

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

> Show that $v^tA^{-1}u\ne -1$ if and only if $A+uv^t$ is invertible, where $A$  square matrix and $u,v \in \mathbb{R}^n$

I feel I want to use eigenvalues. I know,  $A+uv^t$ is invertible if and only if all eigenvalues are non-zero. Any type of proof please.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming $A$ is invertible, you can use [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_determinant_lemma) result (details [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2072706/matrix-determinant-lemma-derivation)) to say that $$\det(A+uv^T)=(1+v^TA^{-1}u)\det A$$

And $A+uv^T$ is invertible iff $\det(A+uv^T)\ne 0$.